# Update multiple rows with updateOrCreate() in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

hi guys i want to update multiple row data or create if not exist with laravel

**the product updated successfully but size no :(**

Products table :

> id

Size table :

> id
>  products_id

**One product can have multiple size**

ProductsController :

```
$data = [
        'desc'           => ucfirst($request->desc), // first lettre upper case
        'foodimages_id'  => $request->img,
        'foodtype_id'    => $request->type,
        'status'         => 1,
        'by'             => $full_name,
        'updated_at'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];

    // Update data
    if ($data) {
        // update product where id = req->$id
        $updateProduct = Product::where('id', $id);
        $updateProduct->update($data);
        if (count($request->size) > 0) {
            // 
            foreach ($request->size as $item => $v) {
                // Get data from text field
                $data2 = [
                    'size'        => ucfirst($request->size[$item]),
                    'price'       => $request->price[$item],
                    'products_id' =>$id,
                    'updated_at'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                ];
                // Update data2
                Foodsize::updateOrCreate(['products_id' =>$id],$data2);
            }
        }
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
```

thnx

Comment: i use Foodsize::updateOrCreate(['size'=>$request->size,'products_id' =>$id],$data2);
work fine but duplicate the first row

Comment: anyone can help me please